# cakephp fails to save entities in loop with MSSQL

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (MSSQL), it is impossible to loop over entity results and save them. The same code was previously working fine with MySQL.

The server will immediately throw this error after the first entity is modified:

**Error: SQLSTATE[HY010]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Function sequence error**

The actual error is occurring on the next iteration of the `foreach` loop after an entity is `save`d. Simple code to demonstrate error:

```
$priceRows = $pricesTable
    ->find()
    ->where(['event_id' => $eventsQuery->id]);

foreach($priceRows as $query) {
    $query->comment = 'new value';
    $pricesTable->save($query);
}
```

I have tried this on both cakephp 3.1.5 and 3.3.3 with the same results. I have spent hours debugging this with no luck.

Comment: try to use $priceTable->get($eventsQuery->id). I think problem is you are trying iterate lazy query object, not entity object

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues in the past.

Try this instead:

```
foreach($priceRows as $query) {
    $pricesTable->patchEntity($query, ['comment' => 'new value');
    $pricesTable->save($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was inspired on @Martin Hrabal comment, so try to change:

```
$priceRows = $pricesTable
    ->find()
    ->where(['event_id' => $eventsQuery->id]);
```

to

```
$priceRows = $pricesTable
    ->find()
    ->where(['event_id' => $eventsQuery->id])
    ->toArray();
```